# Highcharts networkgraph layout

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts library to draw a network graph. But I have a layout problem when the data makes two or more disconnected networks. Then the bigest one is centered and pushes to the edges the other networks to the point where they are barely readable.
Example:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'networkgraph',
    height: '60%'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  plotOptions: {
    networkgraph: {
      keys: ['from', 'to'],
    }
  },
  series: [{
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      linkFormat: ''
    },
    id: 'demo-tree',
    data: [["demo001", "demo002"], ["demo003", "demo004"], ["demo005", "demo002"], ["demo006", "demo007"], ["demo008", "demo009"], ["demo003", "demo010"], ["demo011", "demo009"], ["demo001", "demo008"], ["demo005", "demo001"], ["demo011", "demo008"], ["demo005", "demo006"], ["demo005", "demo007"], ["demo005", "demo011"], ["demo005", "demo009"], ["demo012", "demo004"], ["demo005", "demo008"], ["demo001", "demo006"], ["demo001", "demo007"]],
    nodes: [{ "id": "demo001", "marker": { "radius": 119 }, "color": "#dc3545" }, { "id": "demo002", "marker": { "radius": 7 }, "color": "#ffc107" }, { "id": "demo003", "marker": { "radius": 9 }, "color": "#ffc107" }, { "id": "demo004", "marker": { "radius": 8 }, "color": "#ffc107" }, { "id": "demo005", "marker": { "radius": 100 }, "color": "#dc3545" }, { "id": "demo006", "marker": { "radius": 77 }, "color": "#dc3545" }, { "id": "demo007", "marker": { "radius": 76 }, "color": "#dc3545" }, { "id": "demo009", "marker": { "radius": 40 }, "color": "#dc3545" }, { "id": "demo008", "marker": { "radius": 33 }, "color": "#dc3545" }, { "id": "demo010", "marker": { "radius": 5 }, "color": "#28a745" }, { "id": "demo011", "marker": { "radius": 40 }, "color": "#dc3545" }, { "id": "demo012", "marker": { "radius": 4 }, "color": "#28a745" }]
  }],

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/networkgraph.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jrb471kc/1/

What I want, is to make better use of the space. Rather then having this:
[image: network cramed to the side]
Have something like this:
[image: Both networks visible]

I toyed around with the node.mass attribute to no avail.
Does somebody have a solution for this?

EDIT 1: To better explain my question, this is an example of what I got right now. What I want is the graph to not center the big network in the center. Align it left to have room for the 2 small ones.

[image]

Comment: What about using the `chart.marginRight`? It will increase the free space on the right: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lj0hp7e9/

Comment: Thank you, but this is not really what I am looking for. What I want is to move the big network to the left and leave more room for the smal one on the right.

Comment: The other idea which I can suggest is changing the `layoutAlgorithm.integration` to varlet and `layoutAlgorithm.approximation` to `barnes-hut`, but it will change the design. Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n93m2sjw/